# Faster heroku pushes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

We are using heroku with rails, and the pushes take close to 2 minutes total.

I assume most of the time is spent in compiling slug, assets precompilation and bundle install.

Any tips on how to make this faster?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug_size

Answer (score 2):

Remove all unused .coffe and .scss assets.

Even an empty file can add 10/20ms to asset precompile time.
Also, prefer sprockets' `//=require` over sass' `@import`, it's much faster.

Comment: I have removed anything unused, but still pushes are close to 2 minutes.

Comment: But can you use Compass and //=require ?

Answer (score 2):

To cut down on bundle time, run the following locally after updating your bundle:

```
bundle package
```

Or, to also include gems that obtained from git sources as well:

```
bundle package --all
```

Then, commit your vendor/cache directory to your repo. When you deploy, this will cause Heroku to use the gems from your vendor/cache directory as opposed to downloading all of your gems from your Gemfile.

It will save a little time, and every little bit helps when trying to make deploys faster.